# Смонтировать флешку, на которой была установлена Ubuntu

Tags: linux, usb, lvm

Была у меня система `ubuntu server 11,04` установлена на флешку. Все работало, вот только не очень быстро. Обзавелся винтом и установил систему по новой. Нужно перенести файлы со старой системы, а флешку смонтировать не могу.

```
fdisk -l

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          33      248832   83  Linux
Partition 1 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(0, 32, 33) logical=(0, 33, 3)
Partition 1 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(31, 26, 59) logical=(32, 59, 54)
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2              33        1021     7661569    5  Extended
Partition 2 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(31, 59, 27) logical=(32, 92, 55)
Partition 2 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(985, 13, 52) logical=(1020, 240, 16)
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb5              33        1021     7661568   8e  Linux LVM
```

Пробовал:

```
mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt/sdb5
mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb5 /mnt/sdb5
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb5 /mnt/sdb5
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb5 /mnt/sdb5
```

Comment: если возвращает ощибку внимательно прочитай что ему надо. попробуй первую команду через sudo

Comment: все команды делал под рутом. первая команда писала что неизвестная файловая система LVM Linux а остальные что не верная ФС

Answer (score 1):

Ну, так правильно. Написано же - lvm. Т.е. в сухом остатке - нужно запустить эту службу и настроить ее, чтобы она подцепила раздел с флэш-драйва